# Pass comma-separated string to JSON

Tags: vb.net

I have list of comma-separated string values of 600 characters and I need to pass it to JSON in such a way that 10 characters are loaded and send to the JSON object and then the result needs to be loaded out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add a (small) example of what you have and what you want?

Comment: I have a comma seprated string like string=a,b,c,d,e,f I need it to be sent as a,b c,d so on

Comment: What would the JSON be for that, so that we know exactly what you need?